# Wordpress custom permalink shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress

Working on a Wordpress site and where I need to have a post with php content.
I figured out that this is only possible with a plugin or a shortcode in the functions.php

Googled around, tried a lot but it isn't working out, so i definitely doing something wrong.

code I have in functions.php:

```
function anniversary_link($text) {
        $url = the_permalink();
        return "<a href='$url'>$text</a>";
}
add_shortcode('permalink', 'anniversary_link');
```

And the post I have:
[image]

and the result I get when clicking the link:
[image]

The shortcode has to reference to the single.php page and al the static code's references to the single.php page is just:

```
<?php the_permalink() ;?>
```

Is this te 'correct' way to use href on a post (is there a better/cleaner way to get this working)?

**Edit**

Updated my code thanks to nathan **Edit edit: in functions.php**

```
function anniversary_link( $atts ) {
    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
        'text' => '',
    ), $atts, 'permalink' );

    $url = get_permalink();
    return '<a href="' . $url . '">' . $atts['text'] . '</a>';
}
add_shortcode('permalink', 'anniversary_link');
```

And how I use this short code inside a post (I think that I incorrectly use the shortcode):
[image]

Result:
[image]

**Edit Edit**
This is how I call the dynamic anniversary post:

```
    <?php echo get_posts(array( 'category_name' => 'Anniversary' ))[0]->post_content ;?>
```

(inside the header)
[image]

**solution** thanks to nathan
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading through the code you've posted I see three issues.

1. The way you're accessing the 'text' attribute.
2. The function you're using to get the permalink.
3. The way you're inserting your shortcode into your content.

### Shortcode Attributes

The first parameter of a shortcode callback should be an array of attributes, not a single string. Naming your parameter `$text` has no bearing on the value and won't pull the text attribute of your shortcode.

Change the name of your parameter from `$text` to `$atts` and set a default value for the text attribute. Setting a default value is a good practice with shortcodes and can be done using the `shortcode_atts()` function.

### Return vs. Output Functions

The second issue is your use of `the_permalink()`. `the_permalink()` doesn't return a permalink but outputs it directly instead. As such you can't assign it to a variable.

### The new function

```
function anniversary_link( $atts ) {

    // Set defaults where needed
    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
        'text' => '',
    ), $atts, 'permalink' );

    // Replace the_permalink(). 
    // Given the level of simplicity it doesn't need it's own variable. 
    $url = get_permalink();

    // Put together a new return statement. 
    // Various ways this could be formatted. I went with something clear and easy to understand.
    return '<a href="' . $url . '">' . $atts['text'] . '</a>';
}
```

### Usage

In your code you're using the shortcode inside the `href` attribute of a link. The shortcode returns a full link, not a URL, and therefore shouldn't be inside another `a` tag.

Example:

```
[permalink text="My Link Text"]
// Outputs <a href="http://myurl.com/permalink-here">My Link Text</a>
```

Comment: Nathan! thanks for extensive help! I'am not occasion to try this :(. I will check your answer tomorrow if you don't mind! But for now big thanks for extensive explanation!

Comment: Nathan, I made some time to check out your solution. I am aware of using a array instead of just a simple string. Thanks for that. But I still have struggles on using this short code inside a wordpress post. I will edit my post so I can show you were I go wrong.

Comment: Hi Jim, it would appear your shortcode isn't being picked up at all. Where are you placing the code? How are you outputting the page content?

Comment: Hey Nathan, thanks for responce, I added some extra information. I hope you can see it:o. In the last screenshot the dynamic post is 'ouputting'(?). and the code improvement you gave me is placed inside the functions.php. If the info is still not enough please tell me I will add more (not sure what to add more for now) p.s bad egnlish sorry

Comment: You're accessing the post_content property directly; unless you run it through a filter shortcodes won't be parsed. I'd be inclined to use `echo apply_filters( 'the_content', get_posts...` but I don't know enough about what you're doing to say that's definitely the best option. Instead you could use `echo do_shortcode( get_posts...`

Comment: Nathan! Big thanks for all your help. I had to access the post with the apply_filters. One last question, is this always required? Or only now by some strange reason?